# English version of Me'am Lo'ez on the internet

Tags: product-recommendation

Rabbi Yehoshua Zitron suggested that I study Me'am Lo'ez as a beginner.  Is there a version of Midrash Me'am Lo'ez on the internet in English?

Comment: I assume you mean this work?: https://mysefer.com/Category.aspx?CategoryID=75&CPGR=0&PPGR=0&L=1

Comment: According to this website (which does provide on online index), the actual work is not available online: https://meamloezindex.weebly.com/ . However, you can purchase a print edition through any number of online merchants - though the entire set is pricey.

Answer (score 4):

You can listen to it in English - mp3 format - [here](http://www.englishtorahtapes.com/meam_loez_on_parshas.htm).